# Case statement with in a case statement Spotfire

Tags: case, spotfire

I am trying to use two case statement to create a calculated column but it's not working. Do you have a solution ? Thanks!

```
Case 
            when ${selector}='china' then
                        Case  
                                    when [design]="XXX" then [design] 
                                    when [design]="YYY" then [design] 
                        end


            when ${selector}='japan' then 
                        case
                                    when [design]="AA" then [design]
                                    when [design]="BB" then [design]
                        end

end
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Sorry, in spotfire i can't go further it's telling me that mytable.china doesn't exist. But my selector is a fixed value as such as : china, japan etc... @GordonLinoff

Comment: Solved . ${selector} using to insert it as a value: DocumentProperty("CompetitorSelector")='japan'

Comment: You "solved" this? If so, I would suggest closing this question and also reviewing your old questions to accept correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

replace ${selector} 
bye insert it as a value with " DocumentProperty("Selector")='japan' "